# Using newtype in Data.Array.Unboxed with ghc 7.10

Tags: haskell, types, coercion

This worked fine in ghc 7.8.4, but fails in 7.10.3:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Foo where

import qualified Data.Array.Unboxed       as A
import           GHC.Generics             (Generic)

newtype Elt = Elt Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num, Integral, Real, Enum, A.IArray A.UArray, Generic)
type MyArr = A.UArray Int Elt
```

with lots of messages like

```
/tmp/my.hs:9:75:
    Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Elt’
    arising from the coercion of the method ‘Data.Array.Base.numElements’
      from type ‘forall i. A.Ix i => A.UArray i Int -> Int’
        to type ‘forall i. A.Ix i => A.UArray i Elt -> Int’
    Relevant role signatures:
      type role A.Ix nominal
      type role A.UArray nominal nominal
    When deriving the instance for (A.IArray A.UArray Elt)
```

Although the release notes for 7.10 fail to mention it, I see 
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9220#comment:11 admits its a breaking change. But what's the solution – do I really have to create a newtype wrapper for MyArr with helper functions for every usage?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe `UArray` moved from a representational to a nominal role for the element? I wonder why.

Comment: Yes, looks like you will (another argument for `vector` - getting `UnBox` instances is much easier). Even if you wanted to `unsafeCoerce` your way through an `IArray UArray Elt` instance, you can't since the methods you need to implement aren't exported. While I understand why we shouldn't GND here, the fact we can't handwrite our instance of `IArray` makes me a bit unhappy...

Comment: You can import the methods from `Data.Array.Base`.

Comment: @ReidBarton Oh. For some reason I thought that wasn't exposed. Thank you!

Comment: @ReidBarton, I think the necessary `Coercion`s should be exported from `GHC.Arr` and `Data.Array.Unsafe` or some such. That won't give us GND, but will let us `coerce` the methods.

Comment: The reason I chose Array over Vector was being able to use a newtype Int as the index (having int-int-mappings going in both "directions", it's very easy to mix up index vs value without newtypes).

Comment: You can easily write your own set of operations to use arbitrary indices. `index :: Index -> Vector a -> Maybe a; index (Index i) v = v !? i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a wrapper for `MyArr`, but you will have to write out by hand the instance you would previously have derived. A bit of a brute force solution is to `unsafeCoerce` your way through the `IArray` instance manually (the reason you can't `coerce` is the same you can't derive).

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs, ScopedTypeVariables, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Data.Array.Base
import Data.Array.IArray
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Unsafe.Coerce

instance IArray UArray Elt where
  bounds :: forall i. Ix i => UArray i Elt -> (i, i)
  bounds arr = bounds (unsafeCoerce arr :: UArray i Int)                                                                                                                                                                        

  numElements :: forall i. Ix i => UArray i Elt -> Int
  numElements arr = numElements (unsafeCoerce arr :: UArray i Int)

  unsafeArray :: forall i. Ix i => (i,i) -> [(Int, Elt)] -> UArray i Elt
  unsafeArray lu ies = unsafeCoerce (unsafeArray lu [ (i,e) | (i,Elt e) <- ies ] :: UArray i Int) :: UArray i Elt

  unsafeAt :: forall i. Ix i => UArray i Elt -> Int -> Elt
  unsafeAt arr ix = Elt (unsafeAt (unsafeCoerce arr :: UArray i Int) ix)
```